# npm error while installing ionic dependencies

Tags: ionic-framework, npm-install, fsevents, notsupportedexception

After cloning the project code from the Repository, I'm trying to install the npm to update the packages and plugins included. The command used is:

```
npm install
```

It worked well for previous clones. But now it displays the following error:

```
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.12
npm WARN appname@ No repository field.
npm WARN appname@ No license field.
```

When I tried to install **fsevents** using *--verbose*, it is said that the supported OS is Darwin. But it worked in the previous clone. Why not now?

Answer (score 1):

If your a Windows user:

The fsevents warning isn't a problem. It's an optional dependency and isn't needed for this to work on Windows.

But the error still displaying, in order to fix this.

- Open package.json and delete the gulp-watch dependecy
- Manualy  remove the folder (gulp-watch) from the node_modules fordel
- Unload   the Project and uploaded again

The error is gone!!!

There's a issue open to fix this in .net core , but this will work untill then.